# How can I make this xamarin switch renderer code work?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer, custom-renderer

I'm trying to make this switch renderer work but visual studio doens't recognize **CustomSwitch** and compilation fails with message "The type 'local:CustomSwitch' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. (MasterDetailPageNavigation)"

I have **CustomSwitch.cs** in my project folder:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

public class CustomSwitch : Switch
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOffColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOffColor),
          typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),
          Color.Default);

    public Color SwitchOffColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOnColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOnColor),
          typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),
          Color.Default);

    public Color SwitchOnColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbColor),
          typeof(Color), typeof(CustomSwitch),
          Color.Default);

    public Color SwitchThumbColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbImageProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbImage),
          typeof(string),
          typeof(CustomSwitch),
          string.Empty);

    public string SwitchThumbImage
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SwitchThumbImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SwitchThumbImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In project.droid folder I have **CustomSwitchRenderer.cs**:

```
using System;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Widget;
using MasterDetailPageNavigation.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSwitch), typeof(CustomSwitchRenderer))]
namespace MasterDetailPageNavigation.Droid
{
    [Obsolete]
    public class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {
        private CustomSwitch view;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
                return;
            view = (CustomSwitch)Element;
            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)
            {
                if (this.Control != null)
                {
                    if (this.Control.Checked)
                    {
                        this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                    }
                    this.Control.CheckedChange += this.OnCheckedChange;
                    UpdateSwitchThumbImage(view);
                }
                //Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchBGColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);  
            }
        }

        private void UpdateSwitchThumbImage(CustomSwitch view)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.SwitchThumbImage))
            {
                view.SwitchThumbImage = view.SwitchThumbImage.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");
                int imgid = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(view.SwitchThumbImage).GetValue(null);
                Control.SetThumbResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
            }
            else
            {
                Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchThumbColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
                // Control.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.track);  
            }
        }

        private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Control.Checked)
            {
                this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOnColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(view.SwitchOffColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            this.Control.CheckedChange -= this.OnCheckedChange;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant part of my **xaml**:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation.XAML"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation"
             x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.XAML.CompletaCadastroProf"
             BackgroundImageSource="background">
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout>

        <local:CustomSwitch SwitchOnColor="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

 ...
 ...
```

May be I forgot to add some reference, are you guys seeing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `CustomSwitch` does not appear to use any namespace, so it does not match the namespace your declare with `xmlns:local`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,If you do not put your `CustomSwitch` in the root path of this project like this screenshot,
[image]

Please change another Prefix I changed `myswitch` my code like following format.

```
  <myswitch:CustomSwitch SwitchOffColor="Green"  SwitchOnColor="Red"  />
```

If the VS have auto-association namespace,please click the `Alt+Enter`, you will get the following sceenshot. Click the `add xmlns xxxxxxxx`
[image]

If the VS do not No auto-association namespace, you can right click your PCL item, select the `Properties`.
[image]

Then copy the value of default namespace.
[image]

Open your relevant xaml add this `xmlns:myswitch="clr-namespace:xxxxxxx"` :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:myswitch="clr-namespace:SqliteFormsMVVM"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SqliteFormsMVVM.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <myswitch:CustomSwitch SwitchOffColor="Green"  SwitchOnColor="Red"  />


    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

If you have done above settings, this issue is still existed, please close your VS, open your project folder, delete all of `bin` and `obj` folders(xxx,xxx.Android,xxx.iOS folders), in the end, rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I missed to give a namespace for CustomSwitch.cs, just added

```
namespace MasterDetailPageNavigation.XAML
{ 
...
}
```

and everything works now.